# rsync - Exclude files that are over a certain size?

Tags: linux, unix, rsync, file-transfer

I am doing a backup of my desktop to a remote machine. I'm basically doing `rsync -a ~ example.com:backup/` However there are loads of large files, e.g. wikipedia dumps etc. Most of the files I care a lot about a small, such as firefox cookie files, or `.bashrc`. Is there some invocation to rsync that will exclude files that are over a certain size? That way I could copy all files that are less than 10MB first, then do all files. That way I can do a fast backup of the most important files, then a longer backup of everything else.

Comment: Yep, all those `.iso` images or `.mov` screen recordings not only take up valuable space but valuable time. I'm in a race against time to backup my computer before handing it over to the Apple iRepair people who clobber your data even when it's not necessary.

Comment: `Docker.raw` is another!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

There is a `max-size` option:

```
--max-size=SIZE         don't transfer any file larger than SIZE
```

So:

```
# rsync -rv --max-size=1.5m root@tss01:/tmp/dm
```

Will send only files less than 1.5m.

Regarding sizes from man:
The suffixes are as follows: "K" (or "KiB") is  a  kibibyte  (1024),  "M"  (or  "MiB")  is  a  mebibyte (1024*1024),  and "G" (or "GiB") is a gibibyte (1024*1024*1024).  If you want the multiplier to be 1000 instead of 1024, use "KB", "MB", or  "GB".   (Note:  lower-case  is  also  accepted  for  all  values.) Finally, if  the suffix ends in either "+1" or "-1", the value will be offset by one byte in the indicated direction*

Comment: Note however, that --max-size is not a real "exclude", from the man-page: This option is a transfer rule, not an exclude, so it doesn't affect the data that goes into the file-lists, and thus it doesn't affect deletions. It just limits the files that the receiver requests to be transferred.

Comment: @schlicht Valuable information. So how to auto-delete files that were below the `max-size` limit previously and now surpassed such limit when using the `--delete` flag? Is there a smarter way than simply using the [`find` method](https://superuser.com/a/644274/322536) afterwards?